# How would one create a .NET Blazor service wrapped in a NuGet package?

Tags: .net, nuget, blazor

The Blazor service lifetime is really simple, you call the `Services.AddSingleton<*your any class*>();`, `Services.AddTransient<*your any class*>();` or `Services.AddScoped<*your any class*>();` in Program.cs & you register the contents of that class to be accessible via DI in the scope of the runtime.

How would you wrap up a perhaps particularly complex set of functionality into a NuGet package and then create an instance of that in a service in Blazor that has a nice interface for instance?

Like the following:

```
using SomeNuGetPackage_1;
using SomeNuGetPackage_2;
using SomeNuGetPackage_3;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

// add custom services
builder.Services.AddSingleton<NugetPackage_1_serviceClass>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<NugetPackage_2_serviceClass>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<NugetPackage_3_serviceClass>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

No attempt made to create the NuGet package thus far, as not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a **nuget** package that contains an example '**SalesApi**' class that takes two parameters in the constructor. It may look like the following:

```
public interface ISalesApi {}

public class SalesApi : ISalesApi
{
    protected JObject _request;
    public SalesApi(string url, string key)
    {
        _request["url"] = "url";
        _request["userToken"] = ApiAuthenticator.GenerateToken(key);
    }
}
```

From your other solution that references this **SalesApi** nuget package you could instantiate SalesApi in **Program.cs** via dependency injection:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISalesApi, SalesApi>(x => new SalesApi("urlValue", "apiKeyValue"));
```

From there you access the service as you normally would:

```
[Inject]
ISalesApi Api { get; set; }
```

This would be the most simple implementation with a class that takes parameters. You could use the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or create your own service collection. There are lots of different ways to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

All the code should be in library project.

You can then define an Extension class within the library.  Here's one of mine.

```cs
namespace Blazr.App.Core;

public static class CustomerCoreServices
{
    public static void AddCustomerCoreServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IListPresenter<Customer, CustomerEntityService>, ListPresenter<Customer, CustomerEntityService>>();
        services.AddScoped<CustomerEntityService>();
       //...
    }
}
```

In the actual application you add the services like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddCustomerCoreServices();
//....
var app = builder.Build();
```